# Issue in creating Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource. in com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson-databind

I am facing issue in creating Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource. Only change I did was

updated pom.xml from

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>

to

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.0.pr3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

I am getting following error while executing my project

```
019-10-16 14:04:50.065 [CorrelationId=] ERROR --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatStarter                : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. 
Message: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': 
Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c58725a7]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'resourceConfigCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration$JacksonResourceConfigCustomizer.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceConfigCustomizer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [com/test/test/marketing/banditsorchestrator/config/OwaspConfig.class]: 
Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Failed to introspect Class [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
```

Here is my code

@Configuration
public class OwaspConfig {

```
private  ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    factory.setCharacterEscapes(new OwaspCharacterEscapes());
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
    return new ObjectMapper(factory);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that although it was not specified in the pom, my application was using an older version of jackson-core (2.9.6). Added the following and it fixed my issue.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I identified the outdated dependency using:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Answer (score 0):

updated to 2.10.0 and problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

last but not least: check whether you are not having duplicating dependencies. i spent countless hours trying sort out an issue like yours. the cause was an outdated jackson-core dep, which was over newer one.

Comment: @Jon advised to use `mvn dependency:tree`, i use idea's maven plugin's 'dependencies diagram', which allows to see the tree in advanced view.